# syncronizing forked threads

Tags: multithreading, locking, fork, mutex

I'd like to call fork() from within a signal handler, where the child thread needs to wait for the parent thread to finish a task before completing its tasks.  So for example:

```
   lock=init_lock();
   grab_lock(&lock);
   pid_t child_pid = fork();
   if (child_pid != 0) {
      /* we are the parent */
      build_house();
      release_lock(&lock);
   } else {
      /* we are the child */
      play_in_yard();
      wait_for_lock(&lock);
      enter_house();
   }
```

In this case, you don't want the child entering the house before the parent finishes building it.  (The parent would have to lock *before* forking, to avoid a race condition where the child enters the house before the parents have a chance to grab the lock).  I'm wondering what type of lock I could use.   I'm not seeing any of the locking/unlocking api's in the [async-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) list of functions.   Is there any way to safely do this?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a barrier. Depending on your OS, there are various libraries available such as pthread https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait

Comment: Does `fork()` mean the [unix/posix standard library call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) with that name? If so, it does not create a new thread. It creates a new _process._ IDK what `build_house()` and friends do, but if they must communicate with each other, it won't be as simple as accessing shared variables.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I forgot to specify that the fork was occurring from within a signal handler (hence the requirement for async safety).   I will update the question.

Comment: Even without calling it from a signal handler, the child process may not use any non-async safe functions before calling exec, so you still cannot use locks from the child process.